# iPhone 4 support options

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

My app supports **iOS >= 7.0**

It works fine on all devices except for `iPhone 4` which was reported by one of the live user. Sadly, I don't have `iPhone 4`. Neither is it's simulator available as Xcode no longer supports it.

What all possibilities do I have to test the issue ?

Comment: i have iPhone 4S. I can be a person of your need.

Comment: @pkc456 : Are you also the person available with iPhone 4 ?

Comment: No. I have iPhone 4S, iPhone 6 only.

Comment: @pkc456 : That's fine :) I am looking for iPhone 4.

Comment: Frist what does the iTunes Appstore say about compatibility for your app? Its should then read some thing like: `iPhone 4, iPhone 5, ...` If there is no iPhone 4 in this list then you are having some hardware requirement that is not available on the iPhone 4. You wil need to check your `Required device capabilities` in your apps `info.plist`

Comment: @rckoenes : It says : Requires iOS 7.0 or later. Compatible with iPhone, iPad, iPod touch.

Comment: Can you post the `Required device capabilities` from your apps `info.plist`?

Comment: @rckoenes : 1 Item - armv7

Comment: Just checked this against my, which does run on the iPhone 4, and it should work.

Comment: @rckoenes : Doesn't that entirely depend on the code which you or myself have written ?

Comment: No you can place code in an app that does not work on iOS 7, the app will then just crash. Only the minimal deployment target and the `Required device capabilities` restrict the installation of an app. What you have to do now is find out what is make your app crash, you can get the crash log from iOS 7 with a tool like fabrics crashlytics

Comment: @rckoenes : Firstly, it is unknown which part of code causes crash. Secondly, I already have the base iOS as 7.0. Thirdly, I am not sure if restricting installation of app is the ideal case, as the app installs on iPhone 4 (iOS 7.2.1 which is that of live user).

Comment: @Nitish then you will need to track down the code that is making your app crash. Make sure you do not use any methods/classes/frameworks that are not available in iOS 7. Thus there is no answer that can be given with your code or a crash log.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Project->TARGETS->General`

Check your `Deployment Target` should be `7.0`

like this [image]

Comment: Why not ? My app supports 7.0. And if iPhone 4 has iOS 7.1, it should be fine.

Comment: Right. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score -1):

Can you checkout the iPhone 4's version and make sure it is available? Or you can  alter the app supports > 7.1 and have a try!